# Google Sheets: How to appendRow with 2d getValues array?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Looking for help on this function.

**Background**:
I am creating a Google Sheets based order form for our company, nothing too large its going to support about 100 stores. The problem lies with the operation to append a row to my data collection sheet, database if you will. I'm having trouble with the .appendRow operation.

```
function grabOrder(){
    var ordNum = ss.getRange("B2").getValue();
    var storeCode = ss.getRange("B1").getValue();
    var ordValues = ss.getRange("A1:A100").getValues();

    insertInfo(ordNum, storeCode, ordValues); 
}

function insertInfo(ordNum, storeCode ,ordValues){

    ssDb.appendRow([ordNum, storeCode, ordValues]);

}
```

**Result**: When running my code it doesn't throw an error, it completes the operation and ordNum, storeCode show up properly. However ordValues appears with this:

[Ljava.lang.Object;@78f4b2bd

**Note**: The code I have provided is an extremely simplified version of my code, as my only issue lies with the appendRow array.

**Potential Solution**: I am aware that the getValues grabs a two-dimensional array, and the appenRow will only take one dimensional. My guess is I need to convert the 2d-array into a 1d array and have it stored in a variable? Help please!

**SOLVED**: Here is what I did:

```
var orderString = timeStamp + "," + ordNum + "," + clc + "," + orderRng.toString();
var orderValues = orderString.split(",");
```

I then simply passed the new array like so:

```
ssDb.appendRow(orderValues);
```

Hope you guys find use for this in the future.

Comment: If the values are just a single row in the 2D array, just take the first index value of the 2D array. Like ordNum[0]. Hope that helps!

Comment: Yes but i needed to do this for 100+ values. I have figured it out, by pretty much converting everything to a string and then splitting it as an array.

Answer (score 2):

```
function grabOrder(){
  var ordNum = ss.getRange("B2").getValue();
  var storeCode = ss.getRange("B1").getValue();

  var ordValues = ss.getRange("A1:A100")
    .getValues()
    .map(function (row) {
      return row[0];
    });

  insertInfo(ordNum, storeCode, ordValues);
}

function insertInfo(ordNum, storeCode ,ordValues){
  ssDb.appendRow([ordNum, storeCode].concat(ordValues));
}
```