# Google Script appendRow() fails

Tags: javascript

Everytime I try appendRow() I just get [Ljava.lang.Object;@4ed3710 in my spreadsheet.

```
function my() {    //does not work
  var ssMASTER = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1e4-----vQX');
  var shMASTER = ssMASTER.getSheetByName('master_request');
  var valuesMASTER = shMASTER.getDataRange().getValues();

  var valuesPermaWrt = new Array();
  valuesPermaWrt.push(["WhatEverItem"]); 
  Logger.log("writing:" + valuesPermaWrt);   //Log: WhatEverItem

  ssMASTER.appendRow([valuesPermaWrt]);     //fails
}
```

I followed the solution from elias91:

```
var orderString = timeStamp + "," + ordNum + "," + clc + "," + orderRng.toString();
var orderValues = orderString.split(",");
```

from the [Google Sheets: How to appendRow with 2d getValues array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28308374/google-sheets-how-to-appendrow-with-2d-getvalues-array) 
to create my failed version like here:

```
function blablaArray() {    //does not work
  var ssMASTER = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1e61------IuFV');
  var shMASTER = ssMASTER.getSheetByName('master_request');
  var valuesMASTER = shMASTER.getDataRange().getValues();   
  Logger.log("writing:" + valuesMASTER[0]);  
  //Log: [Timestamp, currently, scheduled in, Pin number]
  var preappendMe = valuesMASTER[0].toString();
  var appendMe = new Array();
  var appendMe = preappendMe.split(",");
  ssMASTER.appendRow([appendMe]);     //fails
}
```

I know appendRow() is described here https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#activate. But copy-pasting variables 10 times seems like a hack rather a programmatic solution, so **I want it to be done through Array** and not like here through each String variable.

```
function blablaSS() {   //works fine
  var ssMASTER = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1e61-----xAU');
  var shMASTER = ssMASTER.getSheetByName('master_request');
 var singularvalue = "ede";
  ssMASTER.appendRow(["a man", singularvalue, "panama"]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)() on your data before appending to the Google Sheet.

```
var valuesPermaWrt = new Array();
valuesPermaWrt.push(JSON.stringify(["WhatEverItem"])); 

ssMASTER.appendRow(valuesPermaWrt);
```